# Can't load CUDA. Tensorflow attempting to load wrong version of cudart64

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I can't get TensorFlow to recognize the 11.1 version of CUDA on my machine.

I've updated path files to the new location but whenever I run training I see it looking for an old version 'cudart64_101.dll' that no longer exists in my file system.

```
'Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found'
```

The current version of the cudart64 dll installed and in my path file is cudart64_110.dll, not the cudart64_101.dll that it is searching for.

I have a windows machine and verified the CUDA installation:nvidia-smi

```
Sun Nov 22 12:11:15 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 456.81       Driver Version: 456.81       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:54:10_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.relgpu_drvr455TC455_06.29190527_0
```

How do I get tensorflow to look for the correct cudart64_110.dll file?

Comment: You can't. You **must** have the version of the CUDA runtime libraries which Tensorflow was built against installed. If you want to use CUDA 11 then you need a version of Tensorflow which was built against CUDA 11

Comment: Thanks very much. I downgraded CUDA to the version compatible with my tensorflow build and that worked a treat.